# DLL call treating jmp instruction as function pointer

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm trying to create a trampoline DLL file to pass glew calls from one DLL to the gl functions inside an exe file to avoid having to manage two instances of glew.

I'm using the standard glew.h header file, my trampoline dll code is like this, but with more of the glew functions defined

```
--- header file ---
#ifndef GL_TRAMPOLINE_H
#define GL_TRAMPOLINE_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

typedef unsigned int GLenum;
typedef unsigned int GLuint;
typedef int GLint;
typedef int GLsizei;
typedef unsigned char GLboolean;
typedef float GLfloat;
typedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptr;
typedef char GLchar;
#define GLAPIENTRY __fastcall
#define exp extern __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" {

typedef void (GLAPIENTRY *VERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC)(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized,
                                                   GLsizei stride, const void *pointer);
exp void __glewVertexAttribPointer(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride,
                                   const void *pointer);
}
#endif

--- cpp file ---
#include "trampoline.h"

HMODULE ModuleBase = nullptr;

void AssureModuleBase() {
    if (ModuleBase == nullptr) {
        ModuleBase = GetModuleHandleW(L"exefile.exe");
    }
}

template <class T>
T GetFunc(LPCSTR name) {
    AssureModuleBase();
    auto ptr = (T*) GetProcAddress(ModuleBase, name);
    assert(ptr != nullptr);
    return *ptr;
}

void __glewVertexAttribPointer(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride, const void* pointer) {
    GetFunc<VERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC>("__glewVertexAttribPointer")(index, size, type, normalized, stride, pointer);
}
```

The error occurs when I try to call the function exported by the dll like so:
`glVertexAttribPointer(...)` which errors with "The code at 0xADDRESS tried to read memory at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. The memory could not be read" and an assertion popup: [image: assertion popup]

Looking at 0xADDRESS it is a call instruction to an offset from rsp, presumably holding the address of my DLL's function (I don't know how to use the debugger well enough to find out), so code execution never reaches my dll in the first place. Printing the address of the function like so `std::printf("%p", &glVertexAttribPointer);` prints an address 0x7FFD4828119A, which contains a jmp instruction.

Attempting to call the function via the function pointer:

```
auto functionPtr = reinterpret_cast<PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC>(&glVertexAttribPointer);
functionPtr(...);
```

works well, which leads me to believe that the function call is trying to interpret the JMP instruction as a function pointer. Unfortunately there are too many glew function calls in the library I'm using for it to be feasible to change all of them, and it feels like the incorrect solution.

I'm using CLion as an IDE, which set up a CMakeLists.txt file for me using CMake version 3.19.2, and MSVC compiler x64 14.16.27023.

Comment: Is it really faulting when it calls the function? Or is this later? Check the call stack when that assertion is tripped. (The "input.cpp" line listed appears to deal with scanf-type inputs.)

Comment: GetProcAddress returns the function pointer, not a pointer to the function pointer

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It faults when it calls the function. I'm not sure why the assertion is tripped there, nothing to do with scanf or reading input is on the call stack.

Comment: @RaymondChen The target isn't really a function even though I'm using GetProcAddress, it's a pointer to the function in the exported symbol.
(exported sym = function ptr)

Comment: Since `T` is already a pointer, cast the `GetProcAddress` result to a `(T)`, and use `return ptr;`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I don't think that's the issue, execution never reaches that DLL, also see my comment to Raymond.

Comment: GetProcAddress returns a pointer to a function. You're telling the compiler it is returning a pointer to a pointer to the function, and dereferencing that. So the compiler reads the first 8 bytes of the function (which could be a jmp instruction) and treats that as the address of the function to call.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Execution doesn't reach there. It crashes trying to call into the DLL that will end up calling GetProcAddress.